# How to efficiently show a users change/update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I have a moments component which is similar to a thread/post. Users can like or dislike this moment. Once they like the moment i call the momentService to retrieve the entire list again so it refreshes and increases the like count of the moment.

However, as im only liking one post its not efficient to update all the other moments. Whats the best way to show this update/change without having to get all the moments again.

When i call the update i retrieve the updated moment object. So is there a way to update this specific moment in the moments object.

**moments.component.html**

```
 <mat-card class="" *ngFor="let moment of moments">
            <mat-card-header class="sub-header" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">

                <mat-card-subtitle>
                    {{moment.created_at}}
                </mat-card-subtitle>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="img-circle">

                </mat-card-title>
                <div>
                    <button mat-icon-button color="warn" matTooltip="Delete" (click)="delete(moment._id)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>

                    <button mat-icon-button>
                        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>
                    {{moment.body}}
                </p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                <div>
                    <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Like" (click)="like(moment._id)">
                        <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon> {{moment.likes.length}}
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Dislike" (click)="dislike(moment._id)">
                        <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon> {{moment.dislikes.length}}
                    </button>
                </div>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Comments">
                        <mat-icon>comment</mat-icon> {{moment.comments.length}}
                </button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
```

**moment.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';
import { MomentService } from '../../../services/moment.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-moments',
  templateUrl: './moments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./moments.component.scss']
})
export class MomentsComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;
  moments: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private momentService: MomentService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.parent.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      let user_id = params.get('id');
      return this.userService.get(user_id);
    }).subscribe((res) => {
      this.user = res;


      console.log(this.user._id);

      this.getMoments();

    });
  }

  getMoments() {
    this.momentService.all(this.user._id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.moments = res.data;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }


  like(moment) {

    let like = { 'like': this.user._id };

    this.momentService.update(moment, like).subscribe((res) => {
      this.getMoments();
      console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  dislike(moment) {

    let dislike = { 'dislike': this.user._id };

    this.momentService.update(moment, dislike).subscribe((res) => {
      this.getMoments();
      console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  delete(moment) {

    let id = moment;

    this.momentService.delete(id).subscribe((res) => {

      this.getMoments();
      console.log(res);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

  }

}
```

**moments.service.ts**

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class MomentService {

    path = 'moment/';

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    create(user_id, moment) {

        let endpoint = this.path;

        return this.apiService.post(endpoint, moment);

    }

    delete(moment_id) {

        let endpoint = this.path + moment_id;

        return this.apiService.delete(endpoint);

    }

    all(user_id) {

        let endpoint = this.path;

        let params = new HttpParams().set('author', user_id);

        return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params);

    }

    get(moment_id) {

        let endpoint = this.path + moment_id;

        return this.apiService.get('endpoint');

    }

    update(moment_id, data) {

        let endpoint = this.path + moment_id;

        return this.apiService.put(endpoint, data);

    }

    search(filters) {

        let endpoint = this.path;

        let params = new HttpParams().set('filters', filters);

        return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params);

    }

}
```

**moment.controller.js (backend api)**

```
update(req, res) {

    let id = req.params.id;


    Moment.findOne({ '_id': id }, (err, moment) => {

        if (req.body.body) {
            moment.body = req.body.body;
        }


        // LIKE&DISLIKE Toggle
        if (req.body.like) {

            if (moment.dislikes.indexOf(req.body.like) > -1) {
                moment.dislikes.remove(req.body.like);
            }

            if (moment.likes.indexOf(req.body.like) > -1) {
                moment.likes.remove(req.body.like);
            } else {
                moment.likes.push(req.body.like);
            }
        }

        if (req.body.dislike) {

            if (moment.likes.indexOf(req.body.dislike) > -1) {
                moment.likes.remove(req.body.dislike);
            }

            if (moment.dislikes.indexOf(req.body.dislike) > -1) {
                moment.dislikes.remove(req.body.dislike);
            } else {
                moment.dislikes.push(req.body.dislike);
            }
        }

        moment.save((err, moment) => {

            if (err) {

                return res.status(404).json({

                    success: false,
                    status: 404,
                    data: {},
                    mesage: "Failed to update moment"

                });
            }

            return res.status(201).json({

                succss: true,
                status: 201,
                data: moment,
                message: "Succesfully updated moment",

            });

        });

    })

}
```

Comment: you better pass that moment id of some sort and then update the likes of that moment only

Comment: you can use find by some moment id and then do the update , the problem is not quite clear

Comment: I just dont think you understand

Comment: yup its not clear

Comment: Sorry i cannot word it any better for you to understand, if you want to tell me whats not clear maybe i can elaborate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the id to the like/dislike methods, you can pass the entire object and from there pass the id to the update method, and on success, mutate the reference.